# cant see the picked image in the document directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

i have used,the below code to store the picked image into documents directory.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
        didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
                  editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{

    UIImage *img = [editingInfo objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd,HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"photo-%@.png",
                           [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPathToFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
    [imageData writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:YES];
       imageView.image=image;
        NSLog(@"path %@",fullPathToFile);// shows the complete image path
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

But unfortunately i cant see the picked image in the document directory, i used 'fullPathToFile' variable content as browser url to check it is available or not..But it is not..
 asking your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :-

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
        didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image
                  editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    UIImage *img = [editingInfo objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd,HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"photo-%@.png",
                           [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPathToFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
    [imageData writeToFile:fullPathToFile atomically:YES];
       imageView.image=image;
        NSLog(@"path %@",fullPathToFile);// shows the complete image path

}
```

Hope it helps you..

Comment: have you tested it in simulator? Check your documents directory in simulator, if image file is created or not

Comment: yeah, i have checked the url...
Users/userName/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/F3535242-FF08-417B-BD08-4F2EAD1D27A2/Documents/

Comment: so is there any image present there?

Comment: yeah.. it shows one another image named: "imageName.png".. dont know how it came.

Comment: I checked your code, and image saving to documents directory is working perfect. Just delete your application and reinstall and check

Comment: in console path shows:/Users/userName/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications/53673A62-CB7B-4321-A71D-A6F2B03BB2DC/Documents/photo-2013-02-11,17:58:03.png..
but it cant see there..

Comment: are you sure you are not removing that image again from documents directory? Or check again in Finder by switching between folders..

Comment: now it worked!!!! earlier imageData was null..
replace: NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);
with: NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
Thanx very much!!!